# How to manually install python-dev from source

Tags: python, linux, installation

I compiled python 2.7.11 as follow steps:

```
tar -xf python.tar.xz
./configure
make
```

after compiling, I found that there is no libpython2.7.so in the results, which means that this is not a 'dev' version.

So, how could I make the .so file and install them properly (Do not override the default python of system) ?

Comment: Note that `-dev` packages (as provided my many distros) do not mean they include a shared library (`.so`) or static library (`.a`). Rather, `-dev` packages provide the *header files* used during compilation.

Answer (score 20):

You need:

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

Check out all that `./configure` has to offer with:

```
./configure --help
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated my question. besides the compiling, I also want to know how to install them (maybe make some symbol links) to the properly dirs. I do not want the system's default python to be override, so the install location should be my home dir, i.e. ~, and add the header and lib dir to compiler's finding path.

Comment: Then configure the prefix in `./configure`. But if you have a new question, please make a new post. Don't forget we're helping you, but others will get help by reading the QA. If it gets too specific and hard to read, then the post looses its value…

Comment: I my case `--enable-shared` worked.  Pay attention whether `configure` yields a message about unrecognized option with `--with-shared`

Comment: Thanks @PauloCarvalho, just to reassure that the option is `--enable-shared` and NOT `--enabled-shared`...