# How to install header files for custom build python?

Tags: python

I install python 3.8.3 from source code, how to install python header files (devel files)?

Comment: Do you mean how to install python-dev manually? Then [look into this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866413/2648551).

Comment: Would you consider `pandas`, `numpy`, and `Beautiful Soup` to be examples of header files? When I was in college, a header file was anything used in conjunction with an `import` statement. For example, when people wrote `import numpy as np` then `numpy` was the header file. I am just asking this in order to clarify the question and be certain about what you are asking.